# Langchain agent always tries to use the tool even when not needed

Tags: langchain

I am using **llama-2-70b-chat.Q5_K_M** together with **langchain 0.0.283** and was able to make it work with simple tooling so that it knows how to extract parameters, pass it to the tool and then parse the response providing the final answer.

The problem starts when using the same chain for asking some general questions where a tool should not be used.
For instance: "What is blue?", "What is the result of 1+1"?
In this case it tried to use the tool with some random parameters.
I now adjusted the main prompt template to kind of force it to use general knowledge first in the following way:

```
template = """You are an helpful assistant trying to answer questions based on your knowledge.
Try not to use any tools first.
Answer the following questions as best you can. In case you can't answer you have access to the following tools (use them only when the problem matches the tool description):

{tools}

When using any tool and it returns "Unknown" answer just stop and provide a final answer that you can't provide any help.
Use the tools only when their description tells that they can help with the certain problem. If you don't know the answer nor can find a relevant tool to help you
just finish saying politely that you won't be able to help with that problem.

Use the following format:

Question: the input question you must answer
Thought: you should always think about what to do
Action: the action to take, should be one of [{tool_names}]
Action Input: the input to the action
Observation: the result of the action
... (this Thought/Action/Action Input/Observation can repeat N times)
Thought: I now know the final answer
Final Answer: the final answer to the original input question

Question: {input}
{agent_scratchpad}"""
```

But even in this case despite not calling any action it did not provide a final answer. Just a following:

```
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
Thought: This is a simple math problem, I can do it.
Action: None needed
```

It's like this chain always expects an action to be called prior providing the Final Answer. Do you know what am I missing here?

Comment: simplify your prompt and try adding well-structured description to your tool. Tool description is one parameter that you can use to control it.